# FPDF images not working in MODx Revo

Tags: fpdf, modx-revolution

I'm using MODx revolution 2.2.1-PL and FPDF to generate some PDFs. I've found that using any images over 100kb (at least around that ballpark) results in them being corrupted in the outputted PDF. It's almost as if the image is still half way through downloading when it is written to the PDF.

This is my snippet which I output onto a page with a blank template:

```
require_once($modx->config['base_path']."assets/fpdf/fpdf.php");

define('FPDF_FONTPATH',$modx->config['base_path']."assets/fpdf/font/");

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('novecentowidedemibold','','novecentowidedemibold.php');
$pdf->SetFont('novecentowidedemibold','',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'text');
$pdf->Image('assets/img/pdf/image.jpg',0,0,-300);
$pdf->Output("myfile.pdf", D);
```

It finds fonts and everything OK, it's just the image that isn't working correctly. If I use a smaller image (filesize), it works. It's definitely finding the image, and the image itself is fine, it's just when printed to the PDF is half there with lots of glitches as if it never finished loading.

If I take this code and execute on the same server but not within MODx the outputted PDF works perfectly regardless of image file size.

Is there something I can do to make sure the image is fully downloaded before the PDF is generated?

Comment: modx has a max file upload size in the manager, though it is by default 1M, perhaps that is affecting your uploads? [check your fpdf settings & docs, it may very well have a max setting as well?]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with anything but the simplest of gifs, went into content types and marked application/pdf that I had created as binary this solved it and I could then see all images.